# Fresh cPanel WHM Install - Can't Login

Tags: centos, webserver, cpanel, centos7, whm

So I have just installed WHM on my CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 64 bit machine using the following command.

```
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

After doing so I went to http://myip:2087 and tried to log in.

For username I put root, for password I put my root password that I can access my machine over SSH with.

I checked my cPanel error log and there is a ton of errors, but I scrolled to the bottom and got you a sample of what I believe the login error is.

```
[2015-10-20 12:21:23 +0200] warn [cpsrvd] Brute force checking was skipped for the “root” from “my.ip.ipv4.form” for the “system” service because the system could not connect to cphulkd. at cpsrvd.pl line 5336.
    cpanel::cpsrvd::connect_cphulkd() called at cpsrvd.pl line 4772
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_form_login() called at cpsrvd.pl line 1067
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_one_connection() called at cpsrvd.pl line 884
    cpanel::cpsrvd::script() called at cpsrvd.pl line 379
[2015-10-20 12:21:28 +0200] warn [cpsrvd] Brute force checking was skipped for the “root” from “my.ip.ipv4.form” for the “system” service because the system could not connect to cphulkd. at cpsrvd.pl line 5336.
    cpanel::cpsrvd::connect_cphulkd() called at cpsrvd.pl line 4772
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_form_login() called at cpsrvd.pl line 1067
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_one_connection() called at cpsrvd.pl line 884
    cpanel::cpsrvd::script() called at cpsrvd.pl line 379
[2015-10-20 12:21:55 +0200] warn [cpsrvd] Brute force checking was skipped for the “root” from “my.ip.ipv4.form” for the “system” service because the system could not connect to cphulkd. at cpsrvd.pl line 5336.
    cpanel::cpsrvd::connect_cphulkd() called at cpsrvd.pl line 4772
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_form_login() called at cpsrvd.pl line 1067
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_one_connection() called at cpsrvd.pl line 884
    cpanel::cpsrvd::script() called at cpsrvd.pl line 379
[2015-10-20 12:22:14 +0200] warn [cpsrvd] Brute force checking was skipped for the “root” from “my.ip.ipv4.form” for the “system” service because the system could not connect to cphulkd. at cpsrvd.pl line 5336.
    cpanel::cpsrvd::connect_cphulkd() called at cpsrvd.pl line 4772
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_form_login() called at cpsrvd.pl line 1067
    cpanel::cpsrvd::handle_one_connection() called at cpsrvd.pl line 884
    cpanel::cpsrvd::script() called at cpsrvd.pl line 379
```

What's the problem, and how do I resolve it? (First time WHM user)

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting while login your WHM with root user? Also Can you please try to disable cPHulk on your server with the following command and try to login it.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/etc/init/stopcphulkd
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/cphulk_pam_ctl --disable
```